# .Net Custom build task for encrypting transformed web.config

Tags: .net, msbuild, task, publish

For publishing my .Net web application I require a custom build task to be called. This task takes the transformed web.config and protects certain sections using a given provider.
The assembly defining the task gets compiled along with the project.

The task requires certain assemblies to be loaded in order to succesfuly protect web.config sections. The required assembly dll's are passed to the task by means of a property, and are then loaded by Assembly.LoadFrom().

I already succeeded in taking the transformed web.config by the $(_WebConfigTransformOutput) property. However, when calling the tool I need the locations of some assemblies that are compiled and included in the package.

My question is how can I reference the dll's that are copied to the PackageTmp dir, I can't seem to find Properties that reference that directory location.

Example of build target (the Encrypt task is my custom included task, $(Somelocation?) must ultimately point to the package bin dir):

```
<Target Name="EncyptWebConfig" AfterTargets="PipelineCollectFilesPhase">
  <PropertyGroup>
  <ConfigFile>$(_WebConfigTransformOutput)</ConfigFile>
  <Sections>
    connectionStrings;
    caracal/authenticationSettings;
    caracal/cookieAuthentication;
    system.net/mailSettings;
  </Sections>
  <!-- The first assembly contains the SecurityProvider,
       The second and third assemblies are for the caracal/* sections
  -->
  <Assemblies>
    $(Somelocation?)\ConfigProtectionAssembly.dll;
    $(Somelocation?)\Caracal.Application.dll;
    $(Somelocation?)\Caracal.AuthenticationModule.dll;
  </Assemblies>
  <Provider>CaracalConfigEncryption</Provider>
</PropertyGroup>

<Encrypt ConfigFile="$(ConfigFile)" Assemblies="$(Assemblies)" Provider="$(Provider)" Sections="$(Sections)"/>
```

Comment: Seems like you'd do better using items rather than a property for the assemblies.